# Bootstrap 4 webpack without modal and carousel elements

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, laravel, webpack

I'm using bootstrap 4.1 in my laravel project.
Bootstrap building with laravel-mix, I would like to use a bootstrap without modal and carousel elements.

```
window._ = require('lodash');
window.Popper = require('popper.js').default;

/**
 * We'll load jQuery and the Bootstrap jQuery plugin which provides support
 * for JavaScript based Bootstrap features such as modals and tabs. This
 * code may be modified to fit the specific needs of your application.
 */

try {
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');

    require('bootstrap');
} catch (e) {}
```

Please help the newcomer in this matter...

Answer (score 0):

Hello all first of all you need to create a new file in the same directory along side with the main js file for example `bootstrap-custom.js`.

Then in `bootstrap-custom.js`  file write the following

```
require('bootstrap/js/dist/alert');
require('bootstrap/js/dist/button');
require('bootstrap/js/dist/carousel');
require('bootstrap/js/dist/collapse');
require('bootstrap/js/dist/dropdown');
require('bootstrap/js/dist/modal');
require('bootstrap/js/dist/scrollspy');
require('bootstrap/js/dist/tab');
require('bootstrap/js/dist/util');
require('bootstrap/js/dist/tooltip');
require('bootstrap/js/dist/popover');
```

* finally include the `bootstrap-cutom.js` in your main js file.

```
window._ = require('lodash');
window.Popper = require('popper.js').default;

/**
* We'll load jQuery and the Bootstrap jQuery plugin which provides 
support
* for JavaScript based Bootstrap features such as modals and tabs. 
This
* code may be modified to fit the specific needs of your application.
*/

try {
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
    require('./bootstrap-custom');
} catch (e) {}
```

Now you have all the scripts in one file you can comment any file you don't need to use.

Comment: I already tried it, after that some elements do not work...
In browser console: Uncaught ReferenceError: Util is not defined

Comment: try to reorder the scripts and move util to the top before the alert

Comment: I answered you with a post below

Answer (score 0):

> *webpack.mix.js*

```
mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');


if (mix.inProduction()) {
    mix.version();
}
```

> *resources/assets/js/app.js*

```
window._ = require('lodash');
window.Popper = require('popper.js').default;

/**
 * We'll load jQuery and the Bootstrap jQuery plugin which provides support
 * for JavaScript based Bootstrap features such as modals and tabs. This
 * code may be modified to fit the specific needs of your application.
 */

try {
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');

    require('./bootstrap');
} catch (e) {}

/**
 * We'll load the axios HTTP library which allows us to easily issue requests
 * to our Laravel back-end. This library automatically handles sending the
 * CSRF token as a header based on the value of the "XSRF" token cookie.
 */

window.axios = require('axios');

window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';

/**
 * Next we will register the CSRF Token as a common header with Axios so that
 * all outgoing HTTP requests automatically have it attached. This is just
 * a simple convenience so we don't have to attach every token manually.
 */

let token = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');

if (token) {
    window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = token.content;
} else {
    console.error('CSRF token not found: https://laravel.com/docs/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token');
}
```

> *resources/assets/js/bootstrap.js*

```
// Bootstrap
require('bootstrap/js/dist/util');
require('bootstrap/js/dist/alert');
require('bootstrap/js/dist/button');
//require('bootstrap/js/dist/carousel');
require('bootstrap/js/dist/collapse');
require('bootstrap/js/dist/dropdown');
//require('bootstrap/js/dist/modal');
require('bootstrap/js/dist/scrollspy');
require('bootstrap/js/dist/tab');
require('bootstrap/js/dist/tooltip');
require('bootstrap/js/dist/popover');
```